# How convert String to [[Int]]

Tags: arrays, swift, type-conversion

```
var str =  "[[1,2,3], [4,0,7], [5,6,8]]"
var digits: [[Int]]
```

How to convert str in digits in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String looks like a json. Try json parsing.

```
let str = "[[1,2,3], [4,0,7], [5,6,8]]"
if let digits = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(str.utf8))) as? [[Int]] {
    print(digits) //[[1, 2, 3], [4, 0, 7], [5, 6, 8]]
}
```

Comment: options it is not needed. Btw there is no need to use if let to convert your string to data. `Data(str.utf8)`

Comment: Thanks ... Updated the answer.

Comment: you can also just force unwrap it considering that it will never fail `data(using: .utf8)!`

Comment: `if let digits = ((try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(str.utf8))) as? [[Int]]) {`

Comment: and change string declaration to let

Comment: Also you can remove the outer parentheses. `if let digits = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(str.utf8))) as? [[Int]] {`

Comment: Thanks.... Instead of force unwraping wouldn't it be better to use `if let, let` ??

Comment: Check my last comment. Btw force unwrap it is ok if you are using utf8. It will never fail

Comment: check Apple forces unwrap it also https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID182